# Did Christopher Langan learn to speak when he was only 6 months old?

Tags: intelligence, learning

According to this [site](http://techblogbiz.blogspot.com/2008/01/all-about-christopher-langan-smartest.html) and many others, Christopher Langan belongs among people with the highest IQ on earth. His IQ is around 195.

They also claim:

> Longan learned to speak when he was only 6 months old and acquired
>   reading ability himself before he was four.

This is just impossible. The mouth isn't even formed for speaking. What is the evidence that he learned to speak at this age? **Or what do they mean he learned to speak?**

I'd like to see 6-month-old baby speaking. Not sure if IQ has anything to do with it.

Comment: To hear my mom say it, I was reading before I was 4.  And I definitely don't have an IQ of 195

Comment: @DenisStallings, I asked about speaking as 6 months old. It is pretty normal now for kids read at the age of 4. They all have electronic devices and access to study alphabet and reading.

Comment: My point was partly made in jest.  In all seriousness though, pretty much all of the sources for information prior to 1999 are Mr. Langan himself.  I'm not sure if this is falsifiable.

Comment: @DenisStallings or provable? Maybe if there is another child capable of speaking at that age? Until then it just means he made it up because it is not humanly possible.

Comment: what i mean by "falsifiable" is a term used by scientists in regards to testing hypothesis.  We can't test whether or not he was speaking at 6 months for obvious reasons.  The only source we have for the claim is Langan himself.  If his mother was alive (she isn't) we could ask her, but a simple good search for "baby's first words six months" returns plenty of examples of parents thinking they said the first words at six months.  So it's entirely possible that Langan's mom thought he spoke at six months, but that wasn't the claim that you asked, so it's not suitable for an answer.

Comment: Count me as another who was reading around the age of 4.  Speaking, though... I still don't do that at all well, and judging from some prominent examples, don't really see that being able to run off at the mouth (or these days, the Twitter account) is a sign of great intelligence :-)

Comment: I wouldn't give too much credence to a site that states "He has achieved the rare feat of around 195 in IQ test or 20/20 in the IQ test." If the writer is using the eyesight measurement 20/20, that is certainly not exceptional. The rest of the article is as poorly written and open to question.

Comment: For someone that is supposedly the smartest man in America, he had a very subpar contribution to Science, a few medíocre articles, and very disrespectful view of education and educators all around. It is very hard to believe that this gentleman could be ranked in any regard more exceptional than so many others that actively contribute to Science. This makes me wonder about how stupid IQ tests really are, and how "valid" something like Mega is.

Comment: I grew up before computers and mobile devices. I could read before I was 4, and I could speak a couple of recognisable words around 6-9 months (literally 2 or 3 words...) So this doesn't sound clever, special or rare. Certainly not an indication of genius level intelligence.

Comment: @Robusto: 20/20 was the name of the [news magazine show](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0124932/) that allegedly confirmed his IQ with a SAT test.

Comment: I tried using [WikiBlame](http://wikipedia.ramselehof.de/wikiblame.php) for the first time, to find when that quote was added and removed from the Wikipedia article to see what references were provided. I couldn't find it. It is the first time I have used WikiBlame and I don't trust it or my search skills, so I don't feel I can draw a strong conclusion from this. Anyone else want a stab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, without any conclusive audio of Langan speaking at 6 months we can't really prove whether he could or could not speak. However, it is possible, though unlikely, that he could speak very simple words that early. Such words would depend on fast physical development rather than high IQ, and wouldn't mean he 'learned to speak'.

The first step on the path to language that (pretty much) all babies go through is called [babbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babbling). Although the *exact* connection between babbling and actual speech is not fully known, the different stages of babbling have been consistently observed in infants worldwide.

The relevant babbling stage here is that at 6 months old most babies can reliably produce the same sounds repeatedly, such as the sound 'ma' to say 'ma ma'. Before this point, babbling is mostly random/inconsistent. The reason for this is because [a baby's larynx is initially high in the throat and descends/begins developing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babbling#Physiology) in their first year of life. About a month after this is when their vocal system has developed enough to produce multiple different sounds in one breath. These abilities to produce and repeat sounds rely on physical development, not intelligence.

**Therefore, unless Langan's larynx descended early to allow his vocal chords to develop a bit more, at 6 months Langan would have only just gained the physical ability to make repetitive sounds**. At 7 months, he'd finally have the ability to produce several different sounds in one breath. Without this ability, coherent words don't seem possible: [articulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulatory_phonetics#Initiation) requires physical control, not intelligence. **However, although this means that he *may* have been able to reproduce very simple, single syllable words at 6 months old, that is both far away from 'learning to speak' and not at all uncommon.**

Comment: If you say it's possible you need to show us at least 1 evidence. Also, your answer doesn't offer references to your observations. You say "perhaps..." well please provide a link where he says what he meant otherwise it's just a speculation.

Comment: @Grasper: That part was just offering some alternatives to what the author meant since you also asked about what the author could have meant by 'learn to speak'. It was mostly to show that there wasn't a good alternative and I had no evidence for any alternative, so I just removed it.

Comment: The far end of "to speak" might also include sign language, which many 6 month olds can start to use a form of.

Comment: Can we at least prove that it is humanly possible? Is there another child speaking fluently sentences at the age of 6 months? If not, you can't say  "it's possible".

Comment: @Grasper: I said that it is not physically possible for him to be speaking fluent sentences, as a 6-month old could, at best, mimic very simple words with their undeveloped vocal chords.

Comment: ok, so basically he was lying about it. That wouldn't add to his intelligence.

Comment: @Grasper: Probably. Him saying his IQ let him talk at 6 months is like saying his IQ let him run at 6 months. It doesn't add to his intelligence, but it certainly adds to his ego, and is probably just one of those unnecessary things said to sound more impressive.

Comment: https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/313128/The-baby-who-can-talk-at-6-months

Comment: @GrahamChiu every child does that. It's up to parents to recognize it and work with it. And I wouldn't say saying eh, ar, ger is "learned to speak". When Izabella was born she opened her eyes and made a clicking sound for milk... and what else she would want? That's just how the mother interpreted it. Can't believe they wrote an article about it. The parents are just pushing pressure on the baby. She will grow up and will be totally normal but with thousand psychological issues because parents pressured her to potty when she was 6 months old. That's just cruel.

Comment: The child created her own language

Comment: @GrahamChiu: 'Created her own language' and 'makes consistent noises her mother can interpret' are very different. It would be more accurate to say that the mother managed [to condition her child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning) a couple months early, which isn't uncommon.

Comment: More accurately would be the child has conditioned the mother.